# Pycharm themes on pycharm 2.7 and osx

Tags: themes, pycharm

Could anyone please explain me where I should place the Pycharm themes?

It seems that all forum posts are for older versions of either osx or pycharm.

I have also tried https://github.com/d1ffuz0r/pycharm-themes with git, but still the themes doesnt appear under "Apperance - themes"

Comment: New PyCharm versions require color schemes to have `.icls` extension instead of `.xml` (and the format is different).

Comment: pycharm-themes is now compatible with PyCharm 3.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what OS you're using for example on Windows they go in
    C:\Users{username}.PyCharm30\config\colors

Reload the application and select the "Settings" from the toolbar
    Editor > Colors & Fonts > Python > Select the desired theme from the dropdown

Comment: That's not themes though. That will affect e.g. individual files being edited but will not affect e.g. menus.